# Matplot data visualization - height argument must be scalar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying my hand at some data visualization with Python and Matplot. In this case I'm trying to visualize the amount of data missing per column. I ran a short script to find all the missing values per column and the result in the array missing_count. I now would like to show this in a bar chart using Matplot but I've run into this issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

missing_count = np.array([33597, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12349, 0, 0, 12349, 0, 0, 0, 115946, 47696, 44069, 81604, 5416, 5416, 5416, 5416, 0, 73641, 74331, 187204, 128829, 184118, 116441, 183093, 153048, 187349, 89918, 89918, 89918, 89918, 89918, 89918, 51096, 51096, 51096, 51096, 51096, 51096, 51096, 51096, 51096, 51096])

n = len(missing_count)
index = np.arange(n)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

r1 = ax.bar(index, n, 0.15, missing_count, color='r')

ax.set_ylabel('NULL values')
ax.set_title('Amount of NULL values per colum')
ax.set_xticks(index + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(list(originalData.columns.values))

plt.show()
```

Resulting in this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-285ca1e9de68> in <module>()
     10 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     11 
---> 12 r1 = ax.bar(index, n, 0.15, missing_count, color='r')
     13 
     14 ax.set_ylabel('NULL values')

C:\Users\Martien\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1895                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1896                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1897             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1898         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1899         if pre_doc is None:

C:\Users\Martien\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in bar(self, left, height, width, bottom, **kwargs)
   2077         if len(height) != nbars:
   2078             raise ValueError("incompatible sizes: argument 'height' "
-> 2079                               "must be length %d or scalar" % nbars)
   2080         if len(width) != nbars:
   2081             raise ValueError("incompatible sizes: argument 'width' "

ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 48 or scalar
```

I've looked at a the Matplot documentation which tells me that height should be a scalar, but it does not reference or explain what this scalar is. There is also [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) example I've followed which does work when I run it.

I've run out of ideas as to why I get this error, all help would really be appreciated.

Edit: originalData is the original CSV file I read in, I only use it here to name my bars

Comment: what do you get when you try type(index)?

Comment: So the height of the bar has to be how many 0s there are in that column? Or are you just trying to plot a bar chart of `missing_count`?

Comment: @DavidG A chart of ;missing_count', I have gathered the amount of NULL values, 0's and 99999's in per column in that array

Comment: @MohammadAthar index is a numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, according to https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

the second argument must be height

you're inputting `n` as the second argument which is a single number

try

```
r1 = ax.bar(index, missing_count, 0.15, color='r')
```

instead, which should get the job done.

Even better, be explicit about your argument names (tedious, and harder to keep clean, but a good ides when you have more than a few arguments)

```
r1 = ax.bar(x=index, height = missing_count, width = 0.15, color='r')
```

the second argument must be height; height corresponds to the count for any particular box.  Say you had an array of zeros and ones

```
A = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1]
```

that would result in a bar plot with two bars, one would be 4 units high (since you have four zeros) the other would be 3 units high

the command

```
r1 = ax.bar([0,1], [4,3], 0.15, color='r')
```

would make a plot with a bar at zero and a bar at 1.  The first bar would be 4 units high, the second would be 3 units high.

Translating to your code, `missing_count` corresponds to the COUNT of the array 
that's not `A`, but instead `[Counter([0,0,0,0,1,1,1])[x] for x in Counter([0,0,0,0,1,1,1])]`

Comment: That seems to work, thank you. But how can it be that the height of the bar chart has to presented in the form of a nparray? Does this argument now double as both the data used and the height?

Answer (score 1):

In the code `n` is scalar. You probably do not want the bar height to be constant, but rather the values from `missing_count`.

```
ax.bar(index, missing_count, 0.15, color='r')
```